# How to get the results of a filtered Mapbox layer?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to update an old Mapbox.js map to Mapbox GL. I am generating the map from geojson (and using coffescript).

```
map.addSource 'my_datasource',
  'type': 'geojson'
  'data': my_geojson

map.addLayer
  'id': 'my_layer'
  'type': 'symbol'
  'source': 'my_datasource'
```

I am filtering the layer based on a user input that returns `value`

```
map.setFilter('my_layer', ["==", 'my_attribute', value ])
```

So far, so good. But now I want to zoom and reposition the map to fit the bounds of the filtered symbols.

I thought I would be able to do something like this

```
bounds = new (mapboxgl.LngLatBounds)
map.queryRenderedFeatures(layers: [ 'my_layer' ]).forEach (feature) ->
  bounds.extend feature.geometry.coordinates
  return
map.fitBounds bounds
```

But `queryRenderedFeatures` appears to be returning all (i.e., un-filtered) symbols.

After much reading around, my understanding is that `queryRenderedFeatures` should return the filtered symbols that are visible in the viewport (i.e., would be suitable for zooming in but not zooming out).

Is this correct? And if so, why is my function above returning unfiltered symbols? Appreciate any advice to help my transition to MapboxGL!

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear to me from the documentation whether filters in the layer should be applied, but in any case, there is an explicit `filter` parameter you can, pass, so:

```
map.queryRenderedFeatures(layers: [ 'my_layer' ],  filter:["==", 'my_attribute', value ]).forEach (feature) ->
  bounds.extend feature.geometry.coordinates
```

But I suspect you really want `querySourceFeatures`, because you don't want to be constrained by what's currently within the viewport:

```
map.querySourceFeatures(my_source,  filter:["==", 'my_attribute', value ]).forEach (feature) ->
  bounds.extend feature.geometry.coordinates
```

or, in native ES2015:

```
map.querySourceFeatures(my_source,  { filter:['==', 'my_attribute', value ]} )
   .forEach (feature => bounds.extend(feature.geometry.coordinates))
```

Comment: thanks @Steve, this looks promising, but is not repositioning the viewport. I think the problem may be that `querySourceFeatures` is returning duplicates, causing bounds to already be met. Within the `forEach` loop I placed `console.log("id: "+feature.properties.id+", coords:"+features.geometry.coordinates)`. Filtering with a value that I know returns only 1 symbol, `querySourceFeatures` returns an array of two objects: `ID: 1, coords: [90,0]` and `id: 1, coords: [-270,0]`. Any idea why this would be? (the data source only contains the +ve coordinates).

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this post, I have added the code which will let you have the features using queryRenderedFeatures() or even using querySourceFeatures():
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66308173/9185662