# How get features from a style's layer in Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm a learner of JavaScript and have a problem with Mapbox GL JS: I have a style in Mapbox Studio, where there is [one my layer — "locations"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MkFF.png). I've added it as a tileset. There are two GeoJSON-points in this layer, but I can't get them in GL JS.
I've found that I should use method `querySourceFeatures(sourceID, [parameters])`, but I have problems with correct filling its parameters. I wrote:

```
var allFeatures = map.querySourceFeatures('_id-of-my-tyleset_', {
  'sourceLayer': 'locations'
});
```

..and it doesn't work.

More interesting, that later in the code I use this layer with method `queryRenderedFeatures`, and it's okay:

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
      var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
        layers: ['locations']
      });

      if (!features.length) {
        return;
      }
      var feature = features[0];
      flyToPoint(feature);
      var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
          offset: [0, -15]
        })
        .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
        .setHTML('<h3>' + feature.properties.name + '</h3>' + '<p>' +
          feature.properties.description + '</p>')
        .addTo(map);
    });
```

I have read a lot about adding layers on a map and know that the answer is easy, but I can't realise the solution, so help, please :)

[Here is](https://github.com/nikita-nikiforov/bilhorod-map/blob/master/index.html) the project on GitHub.

Comment: Btw the link to actually view your page in action: https://rawgit.com/nikita-nikiforov/bilhorod-map/master/index.html

Comment: @SteveBennett Thank you! Quite a useful instrument.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that your map, like all maps created in Mapbox Studio by default, uses auto-compositing. You don't actually have a source called `morganvolter.cj77n1jkq1ale33jw0g9haxc0-2haga`, you have a source called `composite` with many sub layers.

You can find the list of layers like this:

`map.getSource('composite').vectorLayerIds`

Which reveals you have a vector layer called `akkerman`. ("`locations`" is the name of your **style** layer, not your **source** layer). Hence your query should be:

```
map.querySourceFeatures('composite', {
  'sourceLayer': 'akkerman'
});
```

Which returns 4 features.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
Didn't know about 'composite', but now I've changed the query in GitHub as you proposed, and allFeatures variable is empty anyway, you can see this in the console. 
What's wrong?

Comment: I've fixed a mistake and now I get even 8 features, though there are only two in the layer. Strange. But it works anyway. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of questions about `Mapbox get features after filter` or `Mapbox get features before filter`. And I could see there are many posts are scattering around but none of them seem to have a `FULL DETAILED` solution. I spend some time and put both solution together under a function, try this in jsbin.
Here it is for someone interested:

```
function buildRenderedFeatures(map) {
  // get source from a layer, `mapLayerId` == your layer id in Mapbox Studio    
  var compositeSource = map.getLayer(mapLayerId.toString()).source;
  //console.log(map.getSource(compositeSource).vectorLayers);
  var compositeVectorLayerLength = map.getSource(compositeSource).vectorLayers.length - 1;
  //console.log(compositeVectorLayerLength);
  // sourceId === tileset id which is known as vector layer id
  var sourceId = map.getSource(compositeSource).vectorLayers[compositeVectorLayerLength].id;
  //console.log(sourceId);
  
  // get all applied filters if any, this will return an array    
  var appliedFilters = map.getFilter(mapLayerId.toString());
  //console.log(appliedFilters);
   
  // if you want to get all features with/without any filters
  // remember if no filters applied it will show all features
  // so having `filter` does not harm at all 
  //resultFeatures = map.querySourceFeatures(compositeSource, {sourceLayer: sourceId, filter: appliedFilters});
  var resultFeatures = null;

  // this fixes issues: queryRenderedFeatures getting previous features
  // a timeout helps to get the updated features after filter is applied
  // Mapbox documentation doesn't talk about this! 
  setTimeout(function() {
    resultFeatures = map.queryRenderedFeatures({layers: [mapLayerId.toString()]});
    //console.log(resultFeatures);
    }, 500);
  }
```

Then you call that function like: `buildRenderedFeatures(map)` passing the `map` object which you already have when you created the Mapbox map.

You will then have `resultFeatures` will return an object which can be iterated using `for...in`. You can test the `querySourceFeatures()` code which I commented out but left for if anyone needs it.